# How can I merge my object with the matching keys in the other object without breaking it?

Tags: javascript, forms, object, lodash

```
  myData: {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    family: {
       mother: "",
       father: ""
    },
    age: ""
  }

  responseData: {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Doe",
    family: {
      mother: "Jennifer"
    }
    phone: "0123456789",
    weight: 88
  }


  const pick = require('lodash/pick')
  const formKeys = Object.keys(this.myData)
  this.myData = pick(this.responseData, formKeys)
```

myData Output:

```
  {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Doe",
    family: {
      mother: "Jennifer"
    }
  }
```

I want it to be like this

```
  {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Doe",
    family: {
       mother: "Jennifer",
       father: ""
    },
    age: ""
  }
```

myData fields should never be corrupted, if there is a key that does not match, keep that field as it is in the myData.

I want deeper match.

I used lodash(pick) for this. How if it is done with lodash? Or how can I do it any other way?

Comment: Is it only going to be two levels deep or deeper?

Comment: Looks like what you have is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152433/5648954), just partially implemented (you can use `_.assign({}, obj.myData, ...)` to stop `myData` from changing .

Comment: Update question data. I want deeper.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge like below.

```js
const myData = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  family: {
    mother: "",
    father: "",
  },
  age: "",
};

const responseData = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Doe",
  phone: "0123456789",
  weight: 88,
};

const merge = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const merged = { ...obj1 };
  Object.keys(obj1).forEach((key) => {
    merged[key] = obj2[key] ?? obj1[key];
  });
  return merged;
};

console.log(merge(myData, responseData));
```